# Asp.Net Core - Import/Export Engine(.csv and xls format)

Tags: asp.net-core

I am looking for an Import Export Engine compatible with Asp.Net Core and that should handle Composite objects and relations. Please suggest the best Import/Export Libraries or engines available for .csv and xls format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EPPlus plugin

You can check the ff article

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/export-to-excel-in-asp-net-mvc/
http://www.talkingdotnet.com/import-export-xlsx-asp-net-core/